# How to choose String corner cases when taking multiple strings as the parameter in a method?

Tags: java

I'm very confused by the String's corner cases handling about how to choose a proper corner case for a method when taking multiple strings as the parameter.

I understand them from Class StringUtils:

The StringUtils class defines certain words related to String handling.

- null - null
- empty - a zero-length string ("")
- space - the space character (' ', char 32)

But when come to solve problems, I totally have no idea when to choose 
what to be the corner case.

For example, when implementing a similar problem of `string.indexOf()`, the function as below:

```java
public int strStr(String haystack, String needle) {
    if(needle==null|| needle.length()==0) return 0;

    for( int i=0; i<haystack.length();i++){
        if(i+needle.length()>haystack.length()){
            break;
        }
        for( int j=0; j<needle.length();j++){
            if(haystack.charAt(i+j)!=needle.charAt(j)){
                break;
            }
            if(j==needle.length()-1){
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
        return -1;
}
```

Why is the current corner case is correct instead of:

```java
if(haystack==null|| haystack.length()==0) return 0;
```

nor

```java
if(haystack==null|| haystack.length()==0 ||needle==null || needle.length()==0) return 0;
```

nor

```java
if(haystack==null|| needle==null) return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your question is. This is how Apache StringUtils implements the `indexOf` method:

```
public static int indexOf(final CharSequence seq, final CharSequence searchSeq) {
    if (seq == null || searchSeq == null) {
        return INDEX_NOT_FOUND;
    }
    return CharSequenceUtils.indexOf(seq, searchSeq, 0);
}
```

I'm not sure where your method came from or what you're trying to ask.

Comment: this is an interview question I'm practicing on, leetcode 28, it requires to implement an indexOf method, I don't know how to figure out the correct corner case.

Comment: @RioChen What is a corner case? (handling null?) and what is a correct one? Apache StringUtils implements it as seen above, and Apache Commons is a well-respected library, so that "corner case" can be considered the "correct" one, if you will.

Comment: if(needle==null|| needle.length()==0) return 0; is the correct one, others won't be accepted, my question is how to think of what to be the corner case only once to be correct

Comment: @RioChen Sounds like a dumb test, if it considers the very **original** class that you are supposed to be **re-implementing** as incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

From Documentation:

**isBlank(String str)** checks if a String is whitespace, empty ("") or null.

```
StringUtils.isBlank(null)      = true  
StringUtils.isBlank("")        = true  
StringUtils.isBlank(" ")       = true  
StringUtils.isBlank("bob")     = false  
StringUtils.isBlank("  bob  ") = false
```

**isEmpty(String str)** checks if a String is empty ("") or null.

```
StringUtils.isEmpty(null)      = true
StringUtils.isEmpty("")        = true
StringUtils.isEmpty(" ")       = false
StringUtils.isEmpty("bob")     = false
StringUtils.isEmpty("  bob  ") = false
```

If you just want to check only for null or emptiness, then isBlank(str), otherwise isEmpty. 
`if(haystack==null|| haystack.length()==0) return 0;` -> `if(StringUtils.isEmpty(haystack)) return 0;`

About indexOf (StringUtils)
A null CharSequence will return -1.

```
 StringUtils.indexOf(null, *)          = -1
 StringUtils.indexOf(*, null)          = -1
 StringUtils.indexOf("", "")           = 0
 StringUtils.indexOf("", *)            = -1 (except when * = "")
 StringUtils.indexOf("aabaabaa", "a")  = 0
 StringUtils.indexOf("aabaabaa", "b")  = 2
 StringUtils.indexOf("aabaabaa", "ab") = 1
 StringUtils.indexOf("aabaabaa", "")   = 0
```

Parameters:
`seq` - the CharSequence to check, may be null
`searchSeq` - the CharSequence to find, may be null
Returns:
the first index of the search CharSequence, -1 if no match or null string input

Answer (score 0):

You could try with Streams. For example you could create utility class and put it there

```
final long countOfCornerParams = Stream.of(haystack, needle)
                .filter(param -> Objects.isNull(param) || param.isEmpty())
                .count();

        if (countOfCornerParams > 0) return 0;
```